# Why is setlocale() returning false on WPEngine?

Tags: localization

It appears that WPEngine does not have support for different locale strings, rendering `setlocale()` useless.

`setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");` returns `false` and immediately after that, `setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)` (as you would expect from the previous `false`, returns `"en_US"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with `setlocale()` is not the function itself. It is that WPEngine *only* has English language locales installed (the complete list is below) and cannot realistically install any other locales. Because I needed to just print some Spanish language dates (not change the entire WordPress installation to Spanish), I wound up creating an array of the date strings in question and writing a function that parses them if necessary (or sends the result to `strftime()`):

The array is here:

https://gist.github.com/murdaugh/6734488

The function is here (it gets called just like `strftime()`):

https://gist.github.com/murdaugh/6735164

And this is the complete list of WPEngine Locales:

```
en_AG
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_NG
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
```

Answer (score 0):

WP Engine has recently expanded the locales available on their platform. Here is the current list at the time of this reply:

```
C
C.UTF-8
da_DK.utf8
el_CY.utf8
el_GR.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
es_AR.utf8
es_BO.utf8
es_CL.utf8
es_CO.utf8
es_CR.utf8
es_CU
es_CU.utf8
es_DO.utf8
es_EC.utf8
es_ES.utf8
es_GT.utf8
es_HN.utf8
es_MX.utf8
es_NI.utf8
es_PA.utf8
es_PE.utf8
es_PR.utf8
es_PY.utf8
es_SV.utf8
es_US.utf8
es_UY.utf8
es_VE.utf8
fr_BE.utf8
fr_CA.utf8
fr_CH.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
fr_LU.utf8
it_CH.utf8
it_IT.utf8
nl_AW
nl_AW.utf8
nl_BE.utf8
nl_NL.utf8
nn_NO.utf8
POSIX
pt_BR.utf8
pt_PT.utf8
ru_RU.utf8
ru_UA.utf8
sv_FI.utf8
sv_SE.utf8
```

As part of that update, I imagine they should be able to add locales beyond the ones listed above if requested.